# Complete timeseries using empty rows in SQL

Tags: sql, time-series, missing-data, impala

I have a dataset like these

```
Date    ID
201401  1
201402  1
201404  1
201301  2
201304  2
```

And I am trying to fill gaps, plus creating the X obs prev. to my first in the dataset. See example below

```
Date    ID
201311  1
201312  1
201401  1
201402  1
201403  1
201404  1
201211  2
201212  2
201301  2
201302  2
201303  2
201304  2
```

It is always possible to bruteforce it and create every possible date for every ID and then just merge with the final dataset I want based on date and ID; but trying to think of a more efficient solution given the size of the data

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you need a set of every possible date and a set of every possible ID, but you do *not* need to enumerate all the *combinations*. (SQL is great at that.)

```
SELECT dates.date, ids.id
FROM dates
INNER JOIN ids
```

Note that's a `JOIN` without an `ON`. Just join up every possible date with every possible ID.

If you don't have all the dates in one place yet, you're still going to need to create that table before you can move forward. You can do it in a temporary table if needed, but you need to have that list somewhere for the database to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The following will create every combination of date (year and month) and IDs.

```
select y.yyyy + m.mm as yyyymm, d.id
from (select distinct id from dataset ) d
cross join 
(select distinct substring(yyyymm, 1, 4) as yyyy from dataset ) y
cross join 
(values ('01' ),( '02'),( '03') ,( '04'),('05'),('06'),
        ('07'),( '08'),( '09'),('10'),('11'),('12' ))  m(mm)
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are asking.

Comment: @VoteyDisciple  what do you mean by "plus creating the X obs prev. to my first in the dataset"?